# How to view compiled coffeescript result?

Tags: coffeescript

How do I have the javascript generated by coffeescript?

I am having an issue where I have a basic command that blows up with Error:

> msg is not defined

```
module.exports = (robot) ->

  robot.respond /(\S+) ref (\S+)/i, (msg) ->
    msg.send "Calculating..."
    project = msg.match[1]
    dll = msg.match[2]
    exec = require('child_process').exec
    msg.send "variables #{project} and #{dll}"
    msg.send "x"
```

Just depending on magic I could erase most of the code in `robot.respond ->` except 3 messages and sometimes the last one will fail.  I have a feeling some kind of funky white space thing is going on here.  I am using SublimeText editor which should not put garbage characters into my code.

This code uses Hubot, but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 0):

`coffee -c filename.coffee` produces `filename.js`.  In my case, the generated file prevented coffeescript from making any further updates to `filename.js`.  So as I changed my `filename.coffee` file it looked like nothing worked, when in fact the code simply was not changing.  I deleted `filename.js` and the code began working again.